# SQL Lite Issue - Check ('<=now')

Tags: sqlite

Good Afternoon,  I'm struggling with including an input mask into my SQL Lite code as per below -

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;

CREATE TABLE User 
(Customer_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
 Cust_Name vchar(50) NOT NULL, 
 Cust_Add vchar(100) NOT NULL, 
 Cust_Town vchar(50) NOT NULL, 
 Cust_PC vchar(7) NOT NULL, 
 Cust_DOB DateTime DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE CHECK ('<=now') NOT NULL, 
 Cust_Tel vchar(13) NOT NULL, 
 Cust_eMail vchar(50));
```

I'm trying to get the SQL database to not allow entries of DOB's that are greater or equal to today, however when I try to import data, I get an error constraint.  I can't see where I'm going wrong?  The DOB's are most certainly  pre 2017, 1985 to be exact.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated before I rip my hair out.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `CHECK(Cust_DOB <= date('now'))`  ?

Comment: Thank you SO much!

Comment: @peterchen Looks like an answer. Respect for not needing the reputation, but making a nice Q/A pair is a worthy goal, isn't it?

Comment: @Yunnosch: didn't have the time to verify *why* OP's code is behaving the way it does. Added an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CHECK`constraint should be

`CHECK(Cust_DOB <= date('now'))`

See [sqlite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> *Each time a new row is inserted into the table or an existing row is updated, the expression associated with each CHECK constraint is evaluated and cast to a NUMERIC value in the same way as a CAST expression. If the result is zero (integer value 0 or real value 0.0), then a constraint violation has occurred. If the CHECK expression evaluates to NULL, or any other non-zero value, it is not a constraint violation.*

What happened in your statement  is `CAST('<= now' AS NUMERIC)` evaluates to 0 (what you intended as expression is actually a string, that does not start with something that can be interpreted as a number).